# Natural log : Has this proof jumped a step?

Tags: complex-analysis

This proof in Nevanlinna and Paatero's Introduction to Complex Analysis (1969) is meant to show that if $$c_n=\left(1+\frac{z}{n}\right)^n$$ $(n=1,2,\dots,$  and $z = x + iy)$ then $$e^x = \liminf_ {n}|c_n|$$ ($|.|$ denotes the absolute value (corrected from "the real part").

How do they get from Step $2$ to Step $3$? It looks as if the log function has just been ignored, but they're too reputable for that!

Expanding $$|c_n|=\left\lvert1+\frac{x}{n}+i\frac{y}{n}\right\rvert^n
=\bigg(\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y}{n}\right)^2\bigg)^\frac{n}{2}$$

so $$\ln|c_n|=\frac{n}{2}\ln\bigg(1+2\frac{x}{n}+\frac{x^2+y^2}{n^2}\bigg)\tag 1$$

$$=\frac{n}{2}\bigg(\frac{2x}{n}+\left[\frac{1}{n^2}\right]\bigg) = x + \left[\frac{1}{n}\right]\tag 2$$

($[.]$ meaning roughly "of the order of").

So $$\liminf_{n}\ln|c_n|=x\tag 3$$  and $$|c_n|\rightarrow e^x$$ QED.

Comment: The notation is a bit unusual.  Are you using $[f(x)]$ to denote $o(f(x))$ or $O(f(x))$ or something else?  And what does $\{f(x)\}$ mean?  Anyway, it looks like they are just keeping track of the linear term in the usual expansion of $\ln(1+z)$.

Comment: Are you certain that $|.|$ is used to denote the real part and not the absolute value?

Comment: Nevanlinna and Paatero write (page 65): "The expression $[1/n^k]$ denotes a function of $n$ which, when multiplied by $n^k,$ remains bounded as $n \to \infty.$" So, $O(1/n^k).$

Comment: The text uses ${\lim},$ not ${\liminf}.$ (More pedantically: it also uses the notation ${\log},$ not ${\ln}.$) Are you perhaps thinking that the "inf" stands for "infinity"?

Comment: The first line is from $|a+ib|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, if that's what confuses you. And indeed, this uses $|.|$ for absolute value, not real part

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments. I did mistake the absolute value notation and can now see how step 1 works from the absolute value - fine. Sorry if my notation was wrong but I meant to represent the limit as n tends to infinity. However, I still can't see how they get rid of the natural log between steps (1) and (2).

Comment: Re the expression in [ ] in step (2) (5.2 in the original) this does refer to the reciprocal of n, not of the kth power of n, unless here k=1.

Comment: I didn't think the proof could rely on the series expansion of ln - isn't that derived from what it is proving?

Comment: They do seem to be implicitly taking for granted the series expansion of $\log(1 + x)$ for real $x$ with $|x| < 1,$ as well as explicitly taking for granted the properties of the exponential function of a real variable.

Answer (score 1):

This may be the least troublesome derivation.

For $t > 0,$
$$
\log(1 + t) = \int_1^{1 + t}\frac{du}u < \int_1^{1 + t}du = t,
$$
and
$$
\log(1 + t) = \int_1^{1 + t}\frac{du}u >
\int_1^{1 + t}\frac{du}{1 + t} = \frac{t}{1 + t} =
t - \frac{t^2}{1 + t} > t - t^2,
$$
so
$$
0 < t - \log(1 + t) < t^2.
$$
We don't need the detailed inequality, only the consequential
estimate:
$$
\log(1 + t) = t + O(t^2).
$$
This gives us:
\begin{align*}
\log\left(1 + \frac{2x}n + \frac{x^2 + y^2}{n^2}\right) & =
\log\left(1 + \frac{2x}n + O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right) \\
& = \left(\frac{2x}n + O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right) +
O\left(\left(\frac{2x}n + O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)^2\right)
\\ & =
\frac{2x}n + O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right) + O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)
\\ & = \frac{2x}n + O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right),
\end{align*}
whence:
$$
\frac{n}2\log\left(1 + \frac{2x}n + \frac{x^2 + y^2}{n^2}\right) =
x + O\left(\frac1n\right).
$$

Comment: And the derivative of ln x is proved several different ways in another part of this site.

Comment: It's also possible to *define* $\log x$ as $\int_1^x\,dt/t$ (and define ${\exp}$ as the inverse of ${\log}$).